# Fixing overlapping date/time range in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and wondering if there is a way to split the overlapping time range in my data using SQL Server. For example, my current data looks like this:

```
StartDateTime           EndDateTime
2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM      * Overlap
2018-09-17 12:30PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM      * Overlap
2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM 
2018-09-17 02:00PM     2018-09-17 03:00PM  
2018-09-17 03:00PM     2018-09-17 0:00PM
```

As you can see, there is an overlapping time in the current dataset and I'd like to split and rearrange them in ascending order.

The final output would be like:

```
StartDateTime           EndDateTime
2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 12:30PM      
2018-09-17 12:30PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM      
2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM 
2018-09-17 02:00PM     2018-09-17 03:00PM  
2018-09-17 03:00PM     2018-09-17 0:00PM
```

Thank you so much.

---

**Update following first answer**

The code <del>above</del> in the first answer works perfectly with the specific date/time order I listed above as a sample data. But unfortunately, I have another case I needs to work on. The two cases are:

CASE 1. The EndDateTime should be replaced to avoid the overlap.
This case is the same as what I previously asked above.

Original data looks like this:

```
StartDateTime           EndDateTime
2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM      * Overlap
2018-09-17 12:30PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM      * Overlap
2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM
```

I want to get this:

```
2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 12:30PM      
2018-09-17 12:30PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM      
2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM
```

In this case, the EndDateTime should be modified.

CASE 2. The StartDate needs to be fixed.
Original data looks like this:

```
StartDateTime           EndDateTime
2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 12:30PM      * Overlap
2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 01:00PM      * Overlap
2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM
```

I want to get this:

```
2018-09-17 11:00AM     2018-09-17 12:00PM
2018-09-17 12:00PM     2018-09-17 12:30PM      
2018-09-17 12:30PM*    2018-09-17 01:00PM      
2018-09-17 01:00PM     2018-09-17 02:00PM
```

In this case, the StartDateTime should be fixed.

I apologize for the messy data but I can't really manipulate the raw data itself and am really stuck here. I tried to add another CASE WHEN clause to the original solution above, but it didn't work. Is there any way to catch both cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LEAD function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the next 'StartDateTime' onto the current row and use that for further processing.

Then you can compare the next StartDateTime with this row's EndDateTime... if the next row starts before this row's EndDateTime, then modify this row's EndDateTime to be the StartDateTime of the next row.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (StartDateTime datetime, EndDateTime datetime);
INSERT INTO #Test (StartDatetime, EndDateTime) VALUES
('2018-09-17 11:00AM',  '2018-09-17 12:00PM'),
('2018-09-17 12:00PM',  '2018-09-17 01:00PM'),  --   * Overlap
('2018-09-17 12:30PM',  '2018-09-17 01:00PM'),  --   * Overlap
('2018-09-17 01:00PM',  '2018-09-17 02:00PM'),
('2018-09-17 02:00PM',  '2018-09-17 03:00PM'), 
('2018-09-17 03:00PM',  '2018-09-17 04:00PM');  --   Note I changed end to 4:00pm

WITH DateTimeList AS
    (SELECT StartDateTime, 
            EndDateTime, 
            LEAD(StartDateTime,1) OVER (ORDER BY StartDatetime, EndDateTime) AS Next_StartTime
      FROM  #Test)
SELECT  StartDateTime, 
        CASE WHEN EndDateTime > Next_StartTime THEN Next_StartTime 
             ELSE EndDateTime END AS EndDateTime
  FROM  DateTimeList;
```

Results:

```
StartDateTime     EndDateTime
2018-09-17 11:00  2018-09-17 12:00
2018-09-17 12:00  2018-09-17 12:30
2018-09-17 12:30  2018-09-17 13:00
2018-09-17 13:00  2018-09-17 14:00
2018-09-17 14:00  2018-09-17 15:00
2018-09-17 15:00  2018-09-17 16:00
```

Note though that this assumes the overlap is at the *end* of one row and the start (or all) of the next row, and modifies the current row to fit with the next row.

However, if (for example), your two overlapping values were
`12:00 to 12:30` and `12:00 to 1:00` then the first would get modified to be from `12:00 to 12:00` and the second left as is.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this code gives me something else. It replaces both StartDateTime and EndDateTime even when they don't overlap. For example, if I use the code, I get something like (2018-09-17 11:00  2018-09-17 11:00  / 2018-09-17 12:00  2018-09-17 12:00 / etc.) it seems like the startdatetime simply replace the enddatetime.

Comment: I don't think that's correct @alexsmith5123. Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5added52d468bca2d59902fc5998ddb9) with the code from above. As far as I can see it produces exactly the same result as your expected output (except, of course, for the last row 0:00pm which doesn't exist - I changed to 4:00pm).

Comment: Hi, I've figured out why I keep running into an error. It's not because of your code but because of my dataset itself. I just found out there are two different instances where a slightly different modification is needed. I wrote more details about it down below. I'm really stuck with this part all day and any help will be appreciated. Do you know any way to solve the problem I listed below by any chance? Thank you so much again.